# Loading an XML into a List

Tags: c#, xml, xna

I'm trying to take an XML file with multiple items, and load them into a List of that class.

I have managed to add the XML to my project correctly (adding it into a Project Library) and wire it up so that I can load a single item from the XML into a single instance of the class (as below), and be able to access it successfully.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <XnaContent>
        <Asset Type="DataResources.Item">
            <Name>Watermelon</Name>
            <Value>200</Value>
        </Asset>
    </XnaContent>
```

My Item class:

```
namespace DataResources
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Value;
    }
}
```

Then in my main project I load it as follows:

```
Item myItem;
myItem = Content.Load<Item>("Item_Definitions");
```

The problem is that I want to have multiple items in my XML and load them into a List of the Class, so my XML now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type="DataResources.Item[]">
    <Item>
      <Name>Watermelon</Name>
      <Value>200</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Tomato Soup</Name>
      <Value>150</Value>
    </Item>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

My 'Item' class stays the same, however I need to change the Content.Load to be able to handle the list of items:

```
List<Item> myItem;
myItem = Content.Load<Item>("Item_Definitions");
```

...but VS just tells me it can't implicitly convert type 'DataResources.Item' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. I've tried myItem[] and myItem.Add() but I can't find the correct way. The only solutions I can find are pre-4.0 and look horrendous!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't  show use what is the `Content.Load` method performing but anyway you can get all your items into a `List` using `LINQ to XML` like this:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");
List<Item> myItems = xDoc.Descendants("Item")
                         .Select(x => new Item 
                                    { 
                                       Name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                                       Value = (int)x.Element("Value")
                                    }).ToList();
```